# In the Apple App Store Analytics: where is the difference between the KPI "Installations" and "Downloads"? Why is there a gap?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, analytics

I have an app in the Apple App Store and want to understand where the difference between "Installations" and "Downloads" is. In my mind it is only a different word for the same thing but there is a gap in the numbers.

I would be very happy about an answer!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 4):

**Installations** are the total number of times your app has been installed. `Includes redownloads and restores on the same or different device`, downloads to multiple devices sharing the same Apple ID, and Family Sharing installations.

**Downloads** are the number of first-time downloads and redownloads on devices with iOS, tvOS, or macOS. Installations **only includes data from users who have agreed to share their diagnostics and usage information with app developers.**

[image: Screen]

You can see the rate of Opt-in users by clicking `Opt-In Rate History` (*see the image above*)